# Python: Adding column name as a variable to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql

I am struggling a bit with figuring out how I can alter mysql column names in python.

Below is what I ideally want to do:

```
column_name = "Kills"    
my_cur.execute("alter table match_historical_player_stats add  column_name float ")
```

Can someone help me create the correct syntax to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this here:

```
column_name = "Kills"
query = "ALTER TABLE match_historical_player_stats ADD {} FLOAT".format(column_name)

my_cur.execute(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a prepared statement, rather that python formatting. This will make sure that everything is escaped properly.

```
column_name = "Kills"
query = "ALTER TABLE match_historical_player_stats ADD %s FLOAT"
my_cur.execute(query, (column_name,))
```